# Manhwa where sick mc sell everything he got to try and cure himself, and suddenly got transferred to different world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a manhwa, where the story goes like this: the mc is an average joe, working as a salaryman when suddenly he got diagnosed with cancer (stomach cancer if I'm not wrong). After that, he quits his job, and tried everything to find a cure. Eventually he sold everything he has in a journey to find a cure. On his travels, he fell into the sea (if I'm not mistaken) and when he got beached he wakes up in a world quite similar to his old world, but different. He spent quite a while alone while strengthening his frail body in the wilderness, until he met someone that taught him about the existence of magic in this new world.

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/manga/94584/Amanza?

Comment: Sorry, i dont think it is amanza. The story is more action packed, with mc eventually getting stronger and stronger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is [The road of Karma](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=153918).

Almost identical question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/hcyuv6/help_me_find_a_manhwa_mc_is_dying_of_cancer_so_he/).

Syponysis:

> Inhan Kang, a happy-go-lucky librarian, one day receives bad news, that he has cancer. So he starts trying to get medical treatment, when that doesn't work, he starts praying, when that doesn't work, he turns to Chi/Ki techniques. His last try actually works, and his cancer starts stagnating, he continues doing it, until one day, when he gets transported to another world. There he has to start learning how to survive.

[image: Cover]

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much kind stranger